# Laravel - Check if pivot table ID is 'owned' by the user posting it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I want to give all users the option to 'detach' a row from the pivot table - `alert_criteria`, but only if they *own* the 'criteria', which is linked by 'criteria_id' in the pivot table.

**Relationship**

> An Alert belongsToMany Criteria.
>
> A Criteria belongsToMany Alerts.
>
> A User belongsToMany Criteria.

They are currently viewing the data of the pivot table through:

```
$matches = Criteria::whereUserId( Auth::id() )
        ->has('alerts')
        ->get();
```

I want them to have the functionality to be able to delete any of ***their*** rows from the pivot table.

Within my view, I can access each pivot table row's `ID` and post to the controller through:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('archiveMatch', $alert->id), 'role'=>'form')) }}
    @foreach($matches as $match)
        @foreach($match->alerts as $alert) 
            {{$alert->id}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I initially thought of:

```
public function postArchiveMatch($id)
    {
        DB::delete('delete from alert_criteria where id = ?' , array($id));
    }
```

But, I want to check if the user actually own's this pivot table row. As far as I am aware, anyone who knows this URL can delete pivot table rows even if they don't own the 'criteria':

```
  Route::post('users/match/destroy/{id}', 
    array('as' => 'archiveMatch', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postArchiveMatch'));
```

The only long winded way I can think of is:

> Get `criteria_id` relating to `alert_criteria.id`. (from the form post).
>
> Get all `criteria` where `user_id` = `auth::id`
>
> Check to see if the 'criteria_id' is in the list. If not, that means the user doesn't own it.

I'm pretty sure I'm over complicating things but any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You already know which `criteria` that the `user` owns. They are in `$matches`.

Comment: But when the `user` is wanting to delete a row, they're posting the `ID` from the pivot table, not the `criteria_id` associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a range of `criteria_id` in your `delete` query to limit the scope of the query. I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
public function postArchiveMatch($id)
{
    $myCriteriaIds = Db::table('criteria')->select('id')
                                          ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
                                          ->get()
                                          ->toArray();

    $myCriteriaIds = explode(',', $myCriteriaIds);

    DB::table->('alert_criteria')
             ->where('id', $id)
             ->where('criteria_id', 'IN', $myCriteriaIds)
             ->delete();
}
```

Comment: THank you for this @Ben Harold, your logic makes sense. Greatly appreciated! No more banging my head on the desk.